# localhost refuses connection when invoking ASP.NET ashx generic handler

Tags: asp.net, localhost, ashx

I'm developing an ASP.NET website using Visual Studio 2010 on a new machine that was put on my desk; it is running Windows 7 x64. I used to have an XP development box.

The web app has many ASPX pages, and a new ASHX generic handler that emits JSON.  Everything is working fine, including the ASHX, when I launch the app in VS and use Internet Explorer as the client browser.  But when I open the site outside of Visual Studio:

```
              http://localhost/mywebsite/Logon.aspx
```

localhost refuses the connection when the client browser attempts to invoke the ASHX. although the ASPX pages run fine. Fiddler says this at the point the ASHX is invoked:

```
 The socket connection to localhost failed.  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:50312
```

What is different about an ASHX that would cause localhost to refuse the connection while allowing the browser to open ASPX pages?

The ashx does this:

```
        <%@ WebHandler Language="VB"  Class="MyGenericHandler" %>

            Public Class MyGenericHandler
                   Implements IHttpHandler
                   Implements IReadOnlySessionState
```

Comment: Is IIS setup to actually map .ashx files to your .net runtime?  Check your machine.config for a *.ashx handler mapping

Comment: is this 50312 number correct ?